Different Directions in a general curvilinear motion in a plane (Polar Coordinates)
In a polar coordinate system, We define 4 directions:

Radial Direction: Joining the origin with particle's position (represented by r)

Normal Direction: Perpendicular to the curve at a point (represented by n)

Tangential Direction: Tangent to the curve at a particular point as well as perpendicular to the Normal (represented by t)

Transverse Direction: Perpendicular to the Radial Direction (represented by θ)


Is my interpretation correct? Additionally, What is the direction of velocity in such motion? What is the significance of other directions in relation with the kinematical analysis of the planar motion?

Sounds like tangent normal coordinates to me. Polar coordinates doesn't need the curve of the object if I remember correct, they are just coordinates for the family of spheres indexed by radius pretty much.
